# Delete zeros at end of date range for each group

Tags: r, data.table

My data.table looks like this:

```
+------------+--------+
|    Date    | CC  RR |
+------------+--------+
| 31.01.1985 | C1  0.1|
| 28.02.1985 | C1  0.8|
| 29.03.1985 | C1  0.9|
| 30.04.1985 | C1  2  |
| 31.05.1985 | C1  0  |
| 28.06.1985 | C1  0  |
| 31.01.1985 | C2  NA |
| 28.02.1985 | C2  0  |
| 29.03.1985 | C2  0.1|
| 30.04.1985 | C2  0  |
| 31.05.1985 | C2  0.4|
| 28.06.1985 | C2  0  |
```

The `CC` (CompanyCode column) column has unique company codes which identify the company, the `Date` column has dates, and the `RR` column has stock returns. My actual dataset has over 2k companies and a period of 30 years.

My problem is the following: for every company I want to convert the value for `RR` in the last rows for each company from zeros to NAs. Specifically, I want to change the value of `RR` for the following rows from 0 to NA:

- `31.05.1985 | c1`
- `28.06.1985 | c1`
- `28.06.1985 | c2`

I do not want to change intermediate dates such as `28.02.1985 | c2` or `30.04.1985 c2`, and I want to keep existing NAs such as `31.01.1985 | C2`.

I have tried to use

```
length(Data[, CC])-match(unique(Data[,CC]),rev(Test3[,CC]))+1
```

to get a list of indexes of the last occurence of the respective company code and then iterate back until the first non-zero value in the RR column, but I dont know how to apply this on data.table in r...

Of course I could convert all zeros, but this doesn't solve my problem:

```
Date[RR==0, "RR"] <- NA
```

Could someone help me out on this? I would appreciate any help. Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, please post *real useable data* and not ascii art.  I quickly edited what you posted in to a space-delimited file and read it:

```
R> dt <- fread("/tmp/data.txt")
R> dt
          Date CC  RR
 1: 31.01.1985 C1 0.1
 2: 28.02.1985 C1 0.8
 3: 29.03.1985 C1 0.9
 4: 30.04.1985 C1 2.0
 5: 31.05.1985 C1 0.0
 6: 28.06.1985 C1 0.0
 7: 31.01.1985 C2  NA
 8: 28.02.1985 C2 0.0
 9: 29.03.1985 C2 0.1
10: 30.04.1985 C2 0.0
11: 31.05.1985 C2 0.4
12: 28.06.1985 C2 0.0
R> dput(dt)
structure(list(Date = c("31.01.1985", "28.02.1985", "29.03.1985", 
"30.04.1985", "31.05.1985", "28.06.1985", "31.01.1985", "28.02.1985", 
"29.03.1985", "30.04.1985", "31.05.1985", "28.06.1985"), CC = c("C1", 
"C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2"
), RR = c(0.1, 0.8, 0.9, 2, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.4, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x5601c8da9cd0>)
R>
```

The `dput()` output can be evaluated by R and re-creates the data structure.

Next, your data analysis.  First, you want to work by group!  One of the strengths of data.table is the grouping.  Second, you probably want something like "max order indices while zero".  The following should work:

```
R> dt[, rle:=rleid(RR), by="CC"]
R> dt
          Date CC  RR rle
 1: 31.01.1985 C1 0.1   1
 2: 28.02.1985 C1 0.8   2
 3: 29.03.1985 C1 0.9   3
 4: 30.04.1985 C1 2.0   4
 5: 31.05.1985 C1 0.0   5
 6: 28.06.1985 C1 0.0   5
 7: 31.01.1985 C2  NA   1
 8: 28.02.1985 C2 0.0   2
 9: 29.03.1985 C2 0.1   3
10: 30.04.1985 C2 0.0   4
11: 31.05.1985 C2 0.4   5
12: 28.06.1985 C2 0.0   6
R>
```

We use the super-useful `rleid()` function from data.table to get the *index* value of the `rle()` repetition.  Now, we "just" need to group again, and if the `rle` value is equal to the `max(rle)` value we have the position we want and set the value to `NA`.

```
R> dt[, ind:=which.max(rle), by=CC]                # find max index
R> dt[ ind==rle & RR==0.0, RR:=NA_real_, by=CC ]   # at max ind AND zero set NA
R> dt[, ind:=NULL ]                                # remove index helper
R> dt
          Date CC  RR rle
 1: 31.01.1985 C1 0.1   1
 2: 28.02.1985 C1 0.8   2
 3: 29.03.1985 C1 0.9   3
 4: 30.04.1985 C1 2.0   4
 5: 31.05.1985 C1  NA   5
 6: 28.06.1985 C1  NA   5
 7: 31.01.1985 C2  NA   1
 8: 28.02.1985 C2 0.0   2
 9: 29.03.1985 C2 0.1   3
10: 30.04.1985 C2 0.0   4
11: 31.05.1985 C2 0.4   5
12: 28.06.1985 C2  NA   6
R>
```

Again with just the code:

```
dt <- fread("/tmp/data.txt")
dt[, rle:=rleid(RR), by=CC]
dt[, ind:=which.max(rle), by=CC]
dt[ ind==rle & RR==0.0, RR:=NA_real_, by=CC ]
dt[, ind:=NULL ]
dt
```

Comment: Mister Eddelbuettel, thank you for your post. I learned a new function today. I will try to post real useable data next time, sorry for causing the inconvenience. to my data.set: the problem seems to be that my real data set starts with a lot of NAs at the beginning and that the rleid function doesnt seem to count them (it starts as 1 and stays at 1 until the first non NA value). Can I cirvumvent this somehow? even when I put 0 instead of NA in my rr column the rleid function doesnt count up until the first non zero value. thanks in advance.

Comment: Your are welcome.  As for your new questions, I cannot replicate that. ` rleid(100+c(NA,1,2,3,3,3,4))` works with or without the leading NA.  But if you found the answer to your original question useful, please feel to accept either this or the other answer by clicking on the "tick mark". Only you as the one who asked the question can do that.

Comment: thank you, my problem is solved now. I just accepted both answers.

Comment: @AahuM - unfortunately, only one answer can be "accepted" with the green check mark, but I feel no shame playing second fiddle to Dr. Eddelbuettel.  I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/400575) to be a helpful resource when I was just becoming active on SO, and wanted to share it with you.

Answer (score 2):

One approach with `data.table`:

Sort dates from old to new and then create a cumulative sum of `rr`. Then all rows where the cumsum is 0, we change `rr` to `NA`.  Note that because `cumsum` doesn't have an `na.rm` arg, there are a couple of extra steps.

```
# create example data
df <- data.frame(
    date = rep(seq(as.Date("1985-01-31"), by="day", length.out=6), 2),
    cc   = rep(c("c1", "c2"), each=6),
    rr   = c(0.1, 0.8, 0.9, 2, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.4, 0),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# change to data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# sort date old to new
df <- df[order(cc, -date)]

# save a copy of the rr col
df[ , rr_orig := rr]

# turn NAs into 0s because no "na.rm" arg in cumsum
df[is.na(rr), rr := 0]

# create cumsum
df[ , cumrr := cumsum(rr), by=cc]

# replace 0s with NAs in rr, wherever cumsum is 0
df[cumrr == 0, rr := NA]

# put the NAs back into rr from rr_orig
df[is.na(rr_orig), rr := NA]

# clean up by deleting rr_orig and cumrr cols, and re-sort date
df[ , c("rr_orig", "cumrr") := NULL]
df <- df[order(cc, date)]
```

Result

```
> df
          date cc  rr
 1: 1985-01-31 c1 0.1
 2: 1985-02-01 c1 0.8
 3: 1985-02-02 c1 0.9
 4: 1985-02-03 c1 2.0
 5: 1985-02-04 c1  NA
 6: 1985-02-05 c1  NA
 7: 1985-01-31 c2  NA
 8: 1985-02-01 c2 0.0
 9: 1985-02-02 c2 0.1
10: 1985-02-03 c2 0.0
11: 1985-02-04 c2 0.4
12: 1985-02-05 c2  NA
```

Comment: Close, but now you end up with `NA` rows whereas the original had only one.

Comment: Ah!  The "until" in the OP's question had me changing zeros at the _beginning_ of the series.  They want to change them at the _end_ of the series.  Sorting by date from old to new before the cumsum should do it.  I'll update my answer.  Thanks Dirk!  (Also, big fan of rcpp :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood, or maybe I do.  Original data has one NA, as I read it he wants three added: two at the end of  `C1` and one at the end of `C2`. Your answer still does not do that.

Comment: Maybe a copy/paste error going between R and SO.  I'll double check code and provide output to ensure.

Comment: Does not work for me:  `Error in order(cc, -date) : object 'cc' not found`. Anyway ...

Comment: Ok, it does _once I move the `setDT()` above the first `order()` call_.  Then I agree.

Comment: thank you so much, Dan and to you too mister eddelhuettel. my post was a bit misleading, I guess. your method worked, dan. I now have to do a few more tests to understand why it did though, especially why cumsum grouped by the respective companycodes was enough to solve this task.

Comment: I was on my way too a solution but was stumped for a bit. I posted it now.  It is a little shorter, and uses the very handy `rleid()` gem from `data.table`.  Please try that on some larger data set.